# Cypher for finding sets of nodes in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database with ingredients and recipes here:  http://console.neo4j.org/?id=3o8y44  I'm using stems to simplify the ingredient names for searching.

I can find individual recipes closest to containing a given list of ingredients like this:

```
WITH split("egg, sugar, milk, flour, salt, butter",", ") as terms  UNWIND  
terms as term  MATCH (stem:Stem {stem:term})-[:STEM_OF]-> 
(ingredient:Ingredient)-[lst:INGREDIENTS_LIST]->(r:Recipe)  WITH r, 
size(terms) - count(distinct stem) as notCovered,  sum(lst.weight) as weight,  
collect(distinct stem.stem) as matched  RETURN r , notCovered,matched, weight   
ORDER BY notCovered ASC, weight DESC
```

What I'd like is to return sets of recipes that together contain a list of ingredients (excluding recipes that individually contain the whole list). So, using the same ingredients:

```
"egg, sugar, milk, flour, salt, butter"
```

as a result I expect: "Flat bread", "Gogel-Mogel"

whose ingredients together make the list of ingredients: (egg, sugar) + (milk, flour, salt, butter).

What would this query be?

Comment: Your current query just reduces the weight on results that require ingredients not in your list... So the the "recipe sets" query doesn't really make sense because it would always want to return the set of all recipes... What exactly is your criteria for "closest to containing a given list"?

Comment: The current working query would answer "What single recipe can I make using as many of my ingredients as possible?" and I believe this is working ok. But I would like to answer "Which sets of recipes can I make that use all of my ingredients?" This is what I need a query for.

Comment: I think I see now what you mean by the first part of your answer, the working query will give recipes that have ingredients other than what's in the list... I'll have to go back and look at that.... thanks